# GetStream-IO Add activity without foreignId to multiple feeds, but these activities share same Id

Tags: java, getstream-io

I'm using the Stream Java client version 1.3.2.

I have three flat `customer` feeds: `customer:101`, `customer:102`, and `customer103`.

There is also a flat `timeline` feed, `timeline:201`, which follows the above three `customer` feeds.

I added an activity to `customer:101`. The activity has the `to` field set to `customer:102` and `customer:103`.

The activity should now be in the three `customer` feeds and the `timeline` feed.

The `foreignId` and `time` fields are not set for that activity. Should I expect the same activity to have different `id`s in the different feeds?

I was under the impression that if I don't set the `foreignId` and `time` fields on an activity, the same activity on different feeds will have different `id`s. But that does not seem to be the case from what I ran so far.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
Feed feedOne = streamClient.newFeed("customer", "101");
FlatActivityServiceImpl<SimpleActivity> feedOneService =
    feedOne.newFlatActivityService(SimpleActivity.class);

Feed feedTwo = streamClient.newFeed("customer", "102");
FlatActivityServiceImpl<SimpleActivity> feedTwoService =
    feedTwo.newFlatActivityService(SimpleActivity.class);

Feed feedThree = streamClient.newFeed("customer", "103");
FlatActivityServiceImpl<SimpleActivity> feedThreeService =
    feedThree.newFlatActivityService(SimpleActivity.class);

Feed timeline = streamClient.newFeed("timeline", "201");
FlatActivityServiceImpl<SimpleActivity> timelineService =
    timeline.newFlatActivityService(SimpleActivity.class);

timeline.follow("customer", "101", 0);
timeline.follow("customer", "102", 0);
timeline.follow("customer", "103", 0);

// Create a new activity
SimpleActivity activity = new SimpleActivity();
activity.setActor("customer:101");
activity.setObject("tweet:1");
activity.setVerb("tweet");
activity.setTo(Arrays.asList("customer:102", "customer:103"));
feedOneService.addActivity(activity);

System.out.println("Feed one activities:");
feedOneService.getActivities().getResults().forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println("Feed two activities:");
feedTwoService.getActivities().getResults().forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println("Feed Three activities:");
feedThreeService.getActivities().getResults().forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println("Timeline activities:");
timelineService.getActivities().getResults().forEach(System.out::println);
```

I got the following output:

```
13:34:11.835 [main] DEBUG i.g.c.a.repo.StreamRepositoryImpl - Invoking url: 'https://us-east-api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/timeline/201/following/?api_key=
13:34:12.323 [main] DEBUG i.g.c.a.repo.StreamRepositoryImpl - Invoking url: 'https://us-east-api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/timeline/201/following/?api_key=
13:34:12.433 [main] DEBUG i.g.c.a.repo.StreamRepositoryImpl - Invoking url: 'https://us-east-api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/timeline/201/following/?api_key=
13:34:12.573 [main] DEBUG i.g.c.a.r.StreamActivityRepository - Invoking url: 'https://us-east-api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/customer/101/?api_key='
Feed one activities:
13:34:12.817 [main] DEBUG i.g.c.a.r.StreamActivityRepository - Invoking url: 'https://us-east-api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/customer/101/?api_key=w&limit=25'
SimpleActivity{id=f3d610da-81df-11e7-8080-80000cce824c, actor=customer:101, verb=tweet, object=tweet:1, target=null, time=Tue Aug 15 13:34:12 EDT 2017, to=[customer:102, customer:103], origin=null, score=null, duration=null}
Feed two activities:
13:34:12.892 [main] DEBUG i.g.c.a.r.StreamActivityRepository - Invoking url: 'https://us-east-api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/customer/102/?api_key=w&limit=25'
SimpleActivity{id=f3d610da-81df-11e7-8080-80000cce824c, actor=customer:101, verb=tweet, object=tweet:1, target=null, time=Tue Aug 15 13:34:12 EDT 2017, to=[customer:102, customer:103], origin=null, score=null, duration=null}
Feed Three activities:
13:34:12.963 [main] DEBUG i.g.c.a.r.StreamActivityRepository - Invoking url: 'https://us-east-api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/customer/103/?api_key=&limit=25'
SimpleActivity{id=f3d610da-81df-11e7-8080-80000cce824c, actor=customer:101, verb=tweet, object=tweet:1, target=null, time=Tue Aug 15 13:34:12 EDT 2017, to=[customer:102, customer:103], origin=customer:102, score=null, duration=null}
Timeline activities: 
13:34:13.012 [main] DEBUG i.g.c.a.r.StreamActivityRepository - Invoking url: 'https://us-east-api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/timeline/201/?api_key=&limit=25'
SimpleActivity{id=f3d610da-81df-11e7-8080-80000cce824c, actor=customer:101, verb=tweet, object=tweet:1, target=null, time=Tue Aug 15 13:34:12 EDT 2017, to=[customer:102, customer:103], origin=customer:103, score=null, duration=null}
```

Is this the expected behavior? I expected them to all have different `id`s.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the confusion on the call about this. Because you're using the To field, it writes the same payload into each of the feeds, which because they have the same `time` field would indeed have the same activity ID value. If you had written the activities in separate calls it should have given different activity ID values.

Issuing a delete using the activity ID, however, is specific only to a single feed, so a call like:

```
feedTwoService.deleteActivity('f3d6...824c');
```

... should delete the activity ONLY from that one feed.

If you *were* using `foreign_id` values, and you used that `foreign_id` in the delete call on the original feed, it would also delete the activity from any feeds that got a copy through follow relationships, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ian!

Comment: I made a call to delete the activity from the `timeline` feed by using the activity id, as in:

`timeline.deleteActivity("f3d610da-81df-11e7-8080-80000cce824c");`

When I print the contents of all the feeds, only the `customer:101` feed contains that activity. The other feeds seem to have that activity deleted...

So I'm not sure what is actually happening.
From what you've mentioned, I should still see the activity in all three of the `customer` feeds, and only the `timeline` activity should be empty.